# Stochastic nested process

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, variance

This is from "Ross, Introduction to Probability Models (10th ed.)", p. 180, exercise 45.

[image: Exercise instructions]

How should one tackle this formally?

Simulation (with Gaussian stepping) suggests the traveler stays at his starting position on average. I am less sure about the standard deviation of the ending position. With small values of $\beta$, it appears the deviation grows somewhat as square root of the number of steps, or perhaps plain linearly. With $\beta$ large, simulation results "blow out" indeterminately.

With $\beta = 0.01$, I started at $x_0 = 100$ for the plot below, and did $10 \, 000$ simulations for every $n$ between 5 and 100 with step 5. Large dots are for mean, from which lines extend upward and downward for the values of the deviation.

[image: Simulation results]